# Extract with regex all url with the word "original" in google sheet

Tags: regex, google-sheets, regexp-replace

I need to extract with `EXTRACTREGEX` function in Google sheet where cells contain these multiple URLs.

```
https://d3m9l0v76dty0.cloudfront.net/system/photos/6065655/index/e369e968933b90bd986ac2f56e2f1e62.jpg 
https://d3m9l0v76dty0.cloudfront.net/system/photos/6065655/original/e369e968933b90bd986ac2f56e2f1e62.jpg 
https://d3m9l0v76dty0.cloudfront.net/system/photos/6065655/large/e369e968933b90bd986ac2f56e2f1e62.jpg 
https://d3m9l0v76dty0.cloudfront.net/system/photos/6065655/large/e369e968933b90bd986ac2f56e2f1e62.jpg 
https://d3m9l0v76dty0.cloudfront.net/system/photos/6065653/index/91a7285d0a2fd9633718865dd0c2bee4.jpg 
https://d3m9l0v76dty0.cloudfront.net/system/photos/6065653/original/91a7285d0a2fd9633718865dd0c2bee4.jpg 
https://d3m9l0v76dty0.cloudfront.net/system/photos/6065653/large/91a7285d0a2fd9633718865dd0c2bee4.jpg 
https://d3m9l0v76dty0.cloudfront.net/system/photos/6065654/index/9cf646b9ee53e4f7844db9eff556580e.jpg 
https://d3m9l0v76dty0.cloudfront.net/system/photos/6065654/original/9cf646b9ee53e4f7844db9eff556580e.jpg 
https://d3m9l0v76dty0.cloudfront.net/system/photos/6065654/large/9cf646b9ee53e4f7844db9eff556580e.jpg 
https://d3m9l0v76dty0.cloudfront.net/system/photos/6065654/large/9cf646b9ee53e4f7844db9eff556580e.jpg 
https://d3m9l0v76dty0.cloudfront.net/system/photos/6065655/index/e369e968933b90bd986ac2f56e2f1e62.jpg 
https://d3m9l0v76dty0.cloudfront.net/system/photos/6065655/original/e369e968933b90bd986ac2f56e2f1e62.jpg 
https://d3m9l0v76dty0.cloudfront.net/system/photos/6065655/large/e369e968933b90bd986ac2f56e2f1e62.jpg 
https://d3m9l0v76dty0.cloudfront.net/system/photos/6065655/large/e369e968933b90bd986ac2f56e2f1e62.jpg 
https://d3m9l0v76dty0.cloudfront.net/system/photos/6065653/index/91a7285d0a2fd9633718865dd0c2bee4.jpg 
https://d3m9l0v76dty0.cloudfront.net/system/photos/6065653/original/91a7285d0a2fd9633718865dd0c2bee4.jpg 
https://d3m9l0v76dty0.cloudfront.net/system/photos/6065653/large/91a7285d0a2fd9633718865dd0c2bee4.jpg
```

The main idea is to extract all URLs containing the word "original" but I get results of all URLs in the cell.

I tried to extract the URL that contains just those that contain the word "original" with this regex.

```
https.+original.+\.jpg
```

But, it takes all the URLs in the text.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=FLATTEN(FILTER(SPLIT(A105, " "), REGEXMATCH(SPLIT(A105, " "), "original")))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=LAMBDA(x, FLATTEN(FILTER(x, REGEXMATCH(x, "original"))))
 (SPLIT(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(B2:B, "(http)", " $1"),,9^9), " "))
```

[image]

or in one cell:

```
=QUERY(LAMBDA(x, FLATTEN(FILTER(x, REGEXMATCH(x, "original"))))
 (SPLIT(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(B2:B, "(http)", " $1"),,9^9), " ")),,9^9)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried it but it does not work for me - result in the screenshot - https://snipboard.io/hErieT.jpg it will be nice to get the result in one cell as with this function I get it in multiple cells above and not accurate results

Comment: @MarkLin can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KSRPnQEdfotUrgGBYJMhpQSOeTVx5QhUzTGZhSTfawM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: will u please share your sheet with one cell result?

Comment: @MarkLin https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QARSs6096FS7f0dHnAcxMa47rGaT42UiJco5q0LSKXs/copy

Comment: Thank you very much for your help it is working but it seems that I get a lot of duplicates, and sorry I didn't mention it at the beginning

Comment: @MarkLin wrap the formula into UNIQUE()